# Strongly typed view resolves wrong type when posted back to action with inherited model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a multi-typed user profile editor for the user account system on a site I am building for a college email system.

I have 3 view models `Administrator`,  `Faculty`,  `Student`  that inherit from a `Person` class. When they display in the view using `EditorForModel()` they display the correct editor just fine, but when I submit changes to the controller they are resolving as the base class (I have verified this using the visual studio debugger) not the correct submitted view model class. So i am losing important editor data when it reaches the action method. How do i make it resolve the proper type when posting this back to the controller without creating a completely separate view for each model type?

Comment: You will no doubt have to write a custom model binder for this purpose.

Comment: what is the point of having editorfor if you can't use inherted types without writing a custom model binder

Comment: It's not the `EditorFor` call that determines what is passed to the Action method.. when the Model Binder looks at the signature of the method it says "Oh look, a `Person` object, I'll create one of those..". Remember, all the server is receiving are form posted values.. there is no (default) way for it to be notified of the client-side editor template type.

Comment: Try this: when you try `var vm = editorModelVM as Administrator` for an `Administrator` view model, does `vm` return a null, or an instance value? Maybe you just need to upcast, is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

```
public class InheritanceBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {

        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;
            object model = modelType.Assembly.CreateInstance(modelType.FullName);

            var inheritedtypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => model.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();
            HttpRequestBase req = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var keys = req.Form.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(q => q != "__RequestVerificationToken").ToList();



            List<KeyValuePair<Type, int>> matches = new List<KeyValuePair<Type,int>>();

            inheritedtypes.ForEach(t => {
                int p_matches = 0;

                Array.ForEach(t.GetProperties(), item =>
                {
                    if (keys.Any(key => item.Name == key))
                        p_matches++;
                });

                matches.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, int>(t, p_matches));
            });




            var bestmatches = matches.Where(q => q.Value == matches.Max(s => s.Value));
            if (!bestmatches.Any())
                throw new TargetInvocationException("Could not determine model to bind based on the form values provided", null);

            var usematch = bestmatches.First().Key;

            object bindObj = Activator.CreateInstance(usematch);



            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => bindObj, usematch);

            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the model you are expecting in your action method is not of type Person?
This may cause you the problem.

Comment: it should be a type of person being received but its the wrong type of person ie i am posting a student and receiving Person losing the data associated with student

Comment: This is normal since the default model binder is using the parameter type of your action method to create an object of.